# Convert old TYPO3 tt_address template in .htm format to newest tt_address

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have just upgraded an old TYPO3 6 to TYPO3 9 and with that all the plugins were updated. Previously I used an old version of tt_address in which I imported a .htm template to display the contacts. I wanted to restore this template/use it again but I cant. Everything changed and I don't really know how to use the fluid template neither how I can implement my old template in the fluid template

I tried to activate the old plugin template, but nothing changed.

I expected it to accept my old template and to render it like it was before in TYPO3 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some notes in the manual about upgrading at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_address/Administration/Updating/Index.html. You need to check out the upgrade wizards.

However, as you do a major upgrade from the whole system, you really should get familiar with fluid_styled_content and fluid. One documentation is https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/Index.html

---

Back to `tt_address`: You should really get switch to fluid as well as the old plugins will be removed soon. Check out the example templates shipped with the extension, copy those to fileadmin (or a custom extension) and adopt what you need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yeah maybe i have to look at that. But the difference between TYPO3 6 and TYPO3 9 is so big :o I thought I could use the old template forever :D

Comment: so maybe just use version 6 forever ;) SCNR

Comment: To continue using version 6 was not an option :p